# Mi script de javascript no hace nada

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hice este script de javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#teatroC').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: '/routet',
            data: {
                llama: teatro
            },
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function success(data) {
                $('#mainPage').html(
                    <article>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido a la Alianza Cultural MEXICO-CHINA</p>
                    <img src="Imágenes/Reflector2.png" alt="bailarines" height="100" width="100" class="center"></img>
                    </article>
                );
            },
            error: function error(data) {

            }
        });
      });

});
```

Pero cuando hago click en el elemento, me manda error 404, ¿algo está mal ahí? En sí lo que quiero que haga es que, cuando el usuario haga click en el botón cuyo id es "teatroC", muestre en la sección llamada "mainPage" ese código que se muestra ahí.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Miren, esto es lo que he cambiado hasta ahora:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#teatroC').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '/Inicio.html',
        data: {
            llama: teatro
        },
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function success(data) {
            $('#mainPage').html(
                '<article>
                <p style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido a la Alianza Cultural MEXICO-CHINA</p>
                <img src="Imágenes/Reflector2.png" alt="bailarines" height="100" width="100" class="center"></img>
                </article>'
            );
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            $('#mainPage').html(
                <p>Error</p>
            );
        }
    });
  });
```

});

Y al revistar la consola me muestra este error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token script.js:13

hosted page injected VM23:4

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () LSANS.ttf:1

Comment: el error 404 es de la petición a routet, cierto? pues ve a ver qué pasa en esa petición y arréglala para que no se vaya por `error` sino hacia `success`.

Comment: El error 404 hace referencia a que la ruta especificada o no fue encontrada, verifica si `url: '/routet'` es la ruta correcta. Saludos.

Comment: ya corregí el error 404, tenía en mi html, en el elemento de lista un href a una página que no existe. Ahora no me manda el error 404 pero no me escribe el código que le mando. Será cosa del id?

Comment: también modifiqué el url: '/routet' y lo puse a la página que verdaderamente hace la request, pero sigue sin hacer nada

Comment: como último agregué un código a la sección de error, pero no parece que haga nada tampoco

Comment: @shiosaku por favor agrega tambien el HTML para que se entienda mejor la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que te manda es a otra página intuyo que #teatroC es una etiqueta a con un href asignado, para que este enlace no tenga efecto debes añadir los iguiente.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Quedando el disparador de la siguiente manera.

```
$('#teatroC').on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '/routet',
        data: {
            llama: teatro
        },
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function success(data) {
            $('#mainPage').html(
                <article>
                <p style="text-align:center;">Bienvenido a la Alianza Cultural MEXICO-CHINA</p>
                <img src="Imágenes/Reflector2.png" alt="bailarines" height="100" width="100" class="center"></img>
                </article>
            );
        },
        error: function error(data) {

        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

De todas maneras ayudaría compartir la información que te muestrre la consola. Esto lo puedes ver en la mayoría de navegadores con las teclas Ctrl + Mayus + I.

También puedes probar a colocar las siguientes comillas ` al inicio y al final del parámetro de la función html de JavaScript que usas dentro del success.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Buena respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

- en el ejemplo dado, "teatro" parece ser una variable pero no dejas pista de que contiene, recuerda que el objeto data debe debe poder convertirse en un JSON válido, es decir que sus propiedades en el último nivel de profundidad deben ser numeros o strings, arrays que contengan numeros y/o strings, usa el debugger del navegador el la sección de red para asegurarte que estas enviando la data correcta.
- en devolución de llamada success, $('#mainPage').html debería recibie texto como parámetro, es decir que debes entrecomillar tu marcadocon comillas simples en este caso, por ejemplo esto `$('#mainPage').html('<div>bienvenidos<div>')`, en lugar de esto `$('#mainPage').html(<div>bienvenidos<div>)`;
- en devolución de llamada error, sería conveniente que pongas un console.log(data) o un punto de debug para inspeccionar el contenido de data, que posiblemente te de más pistas del error.
- por último asegúrate de que incluiste Jquery en la página y no olvides que el debugger del navegador y el resaltado de sintaxis de tu editor favorito son tus mejores aliados para detectar errores.